# How to Checkpoint while using For Each Loop container in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, foreach

How can I use Checkpoints while I am using For Each Loop containers in an SSIS package?  Whenever I try and rerun the package it starts from the beginning of the foreach loop container instead of from where it failed.  The checkpoint seems to have trouble with for each loop containers.  I created a table insert to help me identify where it errored and then I remove the successful ones from the directory and restart it, but that's more of a work around.  I would like it to just start from the failed directory and continue on.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> The Foreach Loop container is another
>   atomic unit of work that can be
>   restarted. However, the checkpoint
>   file does not contain information
>   about the work completed by the child
>   containers, and the Foreach Loop
>   container and its child containers run
>   again when the package restarts.

The technique usually involves moving each file from the directory once it is processed; **[more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140226.aspx)**.